# Swing JComponent.getComponentCount() is always returning 0

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jpopupmenu

I'm confused why this is happening. Ultimately I want to have logic to test the component at index 0, but first I need this method to return accurately. Here is a sample of the code I have that is returning 0:

```
    parentComp.add(saveAsItem);
    parentComp.add(saveItem);
    if(manager.getListConfigurations().size() > 0){
        parentComp.add(loadMenu);
        parentComp.add(removeMenu);
    }
    System.out.println("COUNT: " + parentComp.getComponents().length);
```

That println statement always returns 0. I would think it should either return 2 or 4, depending on if the above condition is met.

This is very strange behavior. I can't seem to understand why it is happening.

### Edit

If I do the following, I get an exception:

```
parentComp.getComponent(0).getClass().getName();

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: No such child: 0
```

so it clearly doesn't think there are any children, yet there are. I'm adding them right there.

### Edit 2

I'm using a class declared as a JComponent, but which gets implemented as either a JMenu or JPopupMenu depending on conditions. In this case, it's been declared as a JMenu. Maybe it's weird JMenu behavior?

Comment: What is `parentComp`? JPanel? JMenu?

Comment: Posting an SSCCE may help.

Comment: Have you tried adding breakpoints and stepping through the code to isolate the issue? You aren't providing enough information here. If I were you, I would add a breakpoint to the first line of code you have provided.

Comment: `I'm using a class declared as a JComponent, but which gets implemented as either a JMenu or JPopupMenu depending on conditions` Which means you are adding JMenuItem's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm using a class declared as a JComponent, but which gets implemented as either a JMenu or JPopupMenu depending on conditions. In this case, it's been declared as a JMenu. Maybe it's weird JMenu behavior?

Presuming you are adding `JMenuItem`'s to a `JMenu`, a `JMenu` deals with addition of `JMenuItem`'s differently because they are added to an underlying `JPopupMenu`, so you should get the `JPopupMenu` of the `JMenu` and count the items contains within this Container. For example:

```
JPopupMenu menu1 = new JPopupMenu();
menu1.add(new JMenuItem("Item1"));
menu1.add(new JMenuItem("Item2"));
countItems(menu1);
JMenu menu2 = new JMenu();
menu2.add(new JMenuItem("Item1"));
menu2.add(new JMenuItem("Item2"));
countItems(menu2.getPopupMenu());//Use the JPopupMenu rather than the JMenu itself)

private static final void countItems(JPopupMenu menu){
    System.out.println("COUNT: " + menu.getComponents().length);
}
```